# Sign-In after April 2023 Patch SharePoint 2016 OnPrem

Tags: cache, distributedcache, sign-in

After installation of SharePoint patches
KB 5002385  AND KB 5002370
(https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/04/11/april-2023-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2016-is-available-for-download/) we struggle with the environment i different ways. Before this update we installed patches in November 2022 with no problem/issues

After this, April 2023, we ran into problems with configuration wizard that didn't finished successfully either in Wizard or by Powershell.
Find that it looked like we had issues with Distributed Cache and we find a fix on that and followed instructions
https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/02/16/trending-issue-distributed-cache-problems-after-applying-january-2023-cu/

After this we got SignIn prompted!! and cannot find any solutions.

We have tried to Remove and then Activate Distribution Cache with no success. Cannot find good information in then ULS logs that helps out.
Please help out! This is your test environment but before install the patches in the production environment we really want to know the cause of this so we don't risk the production environment.

Please let me know if there is any information missing to help out.